# Capture the value of an element on a web page using the coordinates of the element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the coordinates (x, y) of an element on a web page. How do I capture the value stored in that element at that position. More specifically I want to capture the value that is shown on the web page at that particular location.

Is there a way to do this with the Selenium Python bindings?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are avoiding the use of xpath/cssselectors/other locators for locating the element and getting the text/value ?

Comment: I need to capture these values for multiple pages. now the xpath/cssselectors/ and other locators might be different for different pages, but I always want the value from the fixed location on the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Execute the javascript code](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) and get the element using [`elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.elementFromPoint):

```
x = 100 
y = 100
element = driver.execute_script('return document.elementFromPoint({x}, {y});'.format(x=x, y=y)
```